# Correct left aligning items in simplecv (LyX)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, itemize, lyx-layouts

The [simplecv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/simplecv) class (for [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)), provides the *Itemize* environment which is defined in `simplecv.layout` as follows:

```
Style Itemize
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Item_Environment
    LatexName             itemize
    NextNoIndent          1
    LeftMargin            MMN
    LabelSep              xx
    ItemSep               0.2
    TopSep                0.7
    BottomSep             0.7
    ParSep                0.3
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Block, Left
    LabelType             Itemize
    LabelString           "*"
End
```

Using *items* with the paragraph alignment set to *justified* (which is the default), produces a visually correct list of items (screenshot below, left).

I would like to have an *Left* alignment. Trying to do so (i.e. changing through LyX' paragraph settings interface), prints the (default) bullet, on its own, and pushes the text in the next line (screenshot below, right)!

[image][image]

The complete code, **this time using** `{\raggedright ... \par}`, as seen in LyX' LaTeX Source window reads:

% Preview source code

```
%% LyX 2.0.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{berasans}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.4cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\footnotesize\(\bullet\)}
  \def\labelitemii{\footnotesize\(\circ\)}
  \def\labelitemiii{\tiny\ding{71}}
  \def\labelitemiv{\tiny\ding{75}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent \begin{flushleft}
{\raggedright Sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text\par}
\par\end{flushleft}
\item \noindent Sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text
sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample
text\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The visual result, as seen in a larger screenshot, is an incorrect left aligned item and a correctly justified item:

[image: incorecct and correct left alingment of item]

How is it possible to achieve a *correct* Left alignment? Are the `Align`, `AlignPossible` instructions in `simplecv.layout` related?

[Question to self: did I touch some other, global, setting which affects the behaviour in question?]

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, try the mailing list: lyx-users@lists.lyx.org

Comment: Can I read any comments clarifying why this question is (voted as) off-topic?

Comment: Updated the question with complete code and a large(r) screenshot, this time using @Werners' suggestion.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I think this is more about LyX functionality rather than a TeX problem. That might be the reason for off-topic votes.

Comment: @percusse Accepted, as it seems (to me) it is so, after searching... of course. Initially I thought otherwise.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: By the way, I don't find LyX questions to be off-topic here. It is an interface used by some (many?) as the editor-of-choice for (La)TeX. And, since it provides a front-end and removes the user from any low-level TeX, many problems introduced by LyX can still be overridden using ERTs using basic (La)TeX macros. Closing as off-topic would drop a number of users from this site that would most likely not be able to find help elsewhere but on the LyX mailing list (which may not possess the response rate/quality as is found here).

Comment: Adding to the discussion: by accepting, as I answered @percusse, I meant I respect the opinion of folks that consider(ed) this kind of question(s) as off-topic. This, however, does not mean that I agree with their Skepsis. By definition, TeX.SE [is a free, community driven Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about). And I perceive LyX as a related typesetting system. LyX' mailing list is the *best* source to dig when facing problems. However, the *.SE fora, are such a fine way to communicate (democratically). LyX belongs here!

Comment: @Werner: I agree that LyX generally is on-topic here; but not because _there wouldn't be any other good place to ask about it_ (which I know isn't your main reason).

Comment: I've added the final vote for closing since there is an answer and this keeps appearing on the to-be-closed questions list. :) Repeating what is given above **LyX questions are certainly welcome here**

Comment: @percusse Thanks. Just a question: isn't this a bit unfair for the question itself -- to appear as off-topic?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Yes, maybe I should have not vote for it in the first place. I've asked the mods to reopen it.

Comment: @percusse I really don't mind about this one Q&A. After all, it's something minor (from my POV). I just think & wonder about the general "policy".

Comment: @NikosAlexandris No problem. Consistency is a good thing. The general policy is to try to act justly on each occasion instead of blindly clicking buttons which I've failed here, eheh.

Comment: @percusse :D -- Thanks for the feedback, in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LyX inserts the "Don't Indent Paragraph" formatting *before* the alignment environment `flushleft`, which causes the layout problems. Instead, remove the `\noindent` by selecting "Indent Paragraph" from the paragraph settings window:

[image]

Note that the `flushleft` environment automatically sets the paragraph indent to be `0pt`, so there's no need to specify the "No Paragraph Indent" check. Actually, this is done internally via `\raggedright`, so you could also achieve this via two ERTs manually `{\raggedright ... \par}`:

[image]

`\raggedright` sets the paragraph to be "left aligned" while `\par` ensures that the paragraph/bullet is finished - TeX requires this since it sets *lines* of text based on a paragraph basis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can't reproduce your correct example (shrug). I updated my question with more code and a big screenshot. Maybe something else I 've changed elsewhere in the settings? I am trying to trace it.

Comment: I think I found the difference! It is an additional `\noindent` after the `\item` command. However, I don't know precisely where from and why this is coming from. It seems it is related with LyX' selection under: Document > Settings > Text Layout > Separate paragraphs with: **Vertical space**. Switching between *Alignment settings* (within from the *Paragraph Settings interface*), while on **Vertical space** adds the `\noindent` command after the `\item` command.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: The `\noindent` is inserted because you unchecked the "Indent Paragraph" box under Paragraph Settings. Since paragraphs are indented by default, no indentation causes a specific command to be inserted. So, "re-insert" this indentation and the problem should go away. I've update the answer accordingly. Also, update your LyX version to the latest (currently at [2.0.4](http://www.lyx.org/Download)) from your existing 2.0.2.

Comment: Thanks. I also found the way to un-do the `\noindent`, even by keeping *Vertical space* as a *global* setting. LyX 2.0.2 is current in the ubuntu repos. I also run lyx-dev sometimes manually compiled.